# Income investing in rising rates environment

Tags: investing, bonds, interest-rate

I have invested in bonds and REITS ETFs for income. But these investments probably will not do well if interest rates go up. Are there any investments that will do just fine or even benefit when rates go up in coming years?

I have noted that financial stocks can go up when interest rates rise. Are there other stocks/investments that do the same?

Answer (score 1):

Well, stocks will be likely not be negatively affected by a rate increase if nothing else bad happens at the same time.  This is one reason a portfolio should have a balance of stocks and bonds  Actually almost any investment that is not fixed-income will do fine.  Real estate is a special case because high rates can deter some real estate investors.  Lots of things affect real estate prices, though.

If you want to stick with fixed-income, seek out some variable rate bonds or invest in TIPS (inflation and high interest rates often coincide).

Note that it seems clear that rates can't go down much from here.  But it doesn't necessarily follow that we can expect rates to get high any time soon.  As far as I can tell, demographics, economics, and government policy don't imminently point to the kind of high or vacillating rates we saw in the 80's and before.  Of course, no one knows the future...